# How to play button sounds in Cocos2d

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, uibutton

If I create a button like this:

```
CCMenuItemImage *okBtn = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"gameOkBtn.png"
                                                               selectedImage:@"gameOkBtnPressed.png"
                                                                       block:^(id sender)
                                         {
                                             //actions
                                         }];
```

How could I play a sound both on press and on release? In regular iOS dev I can subclass UIButton and add selectors for the UIControl events.

EDIT: Here's the subclass

```
@implementation CCMenuItemImageSound

- (void)selected{
    [super selected];
    [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:kSoundButtonDown volume:0.5];

}

- (void)unselected{
    [super unselected];
    //this method gets called twice when you release the button
    [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:kSoundButtonUp volume:0.5];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In CCMenuItem.m add,

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button.mp3"];
```

in the definition of **-(void) selected** and **-(void) unselected** method under #pragma mark CCMenuItemSprite - CCRGBAProtocol protocol.
 This will play the sound for all CCMenuItemImage items.

**Better option:**
If you wish the effect only for few buttons then you can subclass CCMenuItemImage and override the above mentioned methods.

You need to preload the mp3 somewhere in your code:

```
 [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]preloadEffect:@"button.mp3"];
```

You will also have to add #import "SimpleAudioEngine.h" to your CCMenuItem or the subclass that you create.

Comment: Thanks. This almost works. When I slide my finger off the button, I get the unselected sound. But when I tap the button normally, I get the down (selected) sound and a double sound when I release the button. Any idea why the unselected sound plays twice as you release the button?

Comment: I added the subclass above. In fact "unselected" gets called twice on a normal button tap. Why?

Comment: i just checked.it was being called only once. Did you add a breakpoint and check the stack trace?

Comment: How do I use that to find the problem? I can set a breakpoint on the playSound line. It stops there twice.

Comment: Check the stack trace, see which methods are calling the 'unselected' method. I cant solve your problem cause i am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: It's being called both by CCMenu ccTouchEnded and CCMenu onExit.